# How to retrieve views from LinearLayout after adding to LinearLayout using LinearLayout.addView(checkbox)?

Tags: java, android

I have a LinearLayout and adding dynamic checkboxes to it.

```
  String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");
    String content = intent.getStringExtra("content");


    String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
    String[] contentSplit = content.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < contentSplit.length; i++) {

        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);

        boolean st;

        if(statusSplit[i].equals("1"))
            st=true;
        else
            st=false;

        checkBox.setId(i);
        checkBox.setTextSize(20);
        checkBox.setText(contentSplit[i]);

      checkBox.setChecked(st);

        linearLayout.addView(checkBox);
       // checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener);

        }
```

This works fine, but hereafter I don't know how to retrieve views again, because I want to be able to change the CheckBoxes text and values. I want to get and edit LinearLayout views again, because I want to check or uncheck a checkbox or edit the checkbox text in case of updating the items.
I use some code like this:

```
switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.edit:
            for(int i = 0; i<linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
               View view =  linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
               CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
               checkBox.setText("new text");
               view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
               view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {

                   }
               });
            }

           case R.id.save:
           // update checkboxes texts and values, then pass them to database.
       }
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you adding `View`s programmatically? You should almost never do this in Android. You probably want a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Because it is a checklist app in order to the users be able to add checklists dynamically. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a perfect case for a `RecyclerView`. Every time the user adds a new item to the list, they're really adding a new item to the `RecyclerView`. Here's a [sample app](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/RecyclerView/) and here's an [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java).

Comment: You can use `checkBox.setTag(...)` & `linearLayout.findViewWithTag(...)` for identification of views but if there are too many checkboxes, then you should use a `RecyclerView` like @GavinWright said.

Comment: @DarShan can you give me an answer for my question? Because I am stuck on getting views again and make checkboxes to setOnCheckedChangeListener in order to be able to update checkbox status and text?